# Просмотр git изменений в android studio

Tags: android-studio, git

Есть ли в Android Studio возможность посмотреть какой пользователь создал или исправил определенный участок кода? Для VS Code есть специальный плагин, есть ли что-то подобное для Android Studio?

Comment: ПКМ -> annotate.